# OnCameraFrame() call TextView/Button setText error

Tags: android, opencv

When I use the `TextView.setText("String")` in `OnCameraFrame(`). There will be a error:

> "thread exiting with uncaught exception".

I don't know why because using the `setText` in `onCameraViewStarted()` or other function is OK. Only in the `OnCameraFrame()` is failing.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for your problem.

Put it where you want in your OnCameraFrame() function.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
      public void run() {
      TextView.setText("AAAA");
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why that would not throw?